# how do I get stdout into variable from flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, process, command-line-interface

I need to store the standard output of a cli command in a variable.
How do I do this?

var result = await Process.run('ls', ['-l']);
print(result.stdout);

I need to execute other unix/os commands - this only works for ls.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

main() async {
  var process = await Process.start('cat', []);
  process.stdout
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .forEach(print);
}
```

you can read more here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process-class.html

Comment: Thank you sir, but this didn't work at all. It produces nothing. So if I did print(process) - nothing is showing.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [Process](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.0/dart-io/Process-class.html) documentation, I came up with the following:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

main() async {
  final process = await Process.start('ls', ['-l']);

  final List<String> standardOutputLines = [];

  await process.stdout
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .forEach(standardOutputLines.add);

  final standardOutput = standardOutputLines.join('\n');
  print(standardOutput);
}
```